# Optimization Rule for fulltext search?

Tags: arangodb

I observe the following AQL to be very slow if it returns many results. Shall there be an optimization rule which uses the limit statement?

```
FOR p IN FULLTEXT(Parts, "texts", "searchterm")
    LIMIT 100
    RETURN p.attribute1
```

Comment: What kind and amount of data is in your collection? How is the fulltext index configured?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently a limitation of ArangoDB.

The current implementation of the fulltext index and its FULLTEXT() function call doesn't allow optimizations in the database core;

Thus the search query is executed and all its results are instanciated.

The limit will then only stop them from being delivered to the client.

Future implementation enhancements may circumvent this behaviour.